# Accessing Array List from another class

Tags: java

Hey how do I access an arraylist from another class? as in call an objects method inside of the arraylist but from the MasterControlPanel class?. Any help is greatly appreciated. Because the get(0) does not seem to be working.

```
//example

public class MasterControlPanel{
    public static Building building = new Building();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        building.rooms.get(0).*whatever*
    }
}

public class Building
{
    public static Rooms rooms[] = new Rooms[4];
    private float outsideTemp;
    ArrayList rooms = new ArrayList();

    rooms.add(*new instance*); 
    rooms.add(*new instance*); 

    public Building() {
    }
```

}

Comment: This won't compile (even once you replace the `*new instance*` bits) because the `rooms.add()` calls aren't in a method, constructor or initialiser. Also yo have both an array and an ArrayList called `rooms`. Can you edit this to make it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you post the actual code? There are two variables with same name in `Building`: `rooms`.

Comment: Is this really your code?  You really have a static variable with the same name as an instance variable?  What's not working?  Show some errors, maybe?

Comment: Yeah sorry, Its just an example, I just need to know if the get(0) should work or not? I was in a bit of a rush, I should of took more care to explain! sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a getter:

```
public class Building{

public static Rooms roomArray[] = new Rooms[4];
private float outsideTemp;
List<Room> rooms;

public Building(float temp){
    rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
    rooms.add(new Room()); 
    rooms.add(new Room());
    outsideTemp = temp;
}

public List<Rooms> getRoomList() {
    return this.rooms;
}
}
```

Then you can do:

```
public class MasterControlPanel{
    public static Building building = new Building();

    public static void main(String[] args){
    building.getRoomList.get(0).*whatever*

    }
}
```

Aside: why aren't you defining the type of your `List`s? Also, note that I've moved code into the Constructor for this class, and fixed name collisions. Also, why the `static` array? Things to think about...

Last note: added `float` to constructor to ensure it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that your ArrayList instance is private and you dont want it to be static(do you?). First of all you create a getter method such as:

```
public ArrayList getRooms()
```

{ 
  return rooms;
}

On the other class now, you create an object:

```
Building b=new Building();
```

And access the list:

```
b.getRooms();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `main()` method is indeed your main method, you probably haven't initialized your `ArrayList`.  Put those `rooms.add(new Thing())` calls where you know they'll be called before you try to access the lists.

```
public class Building {
    public final ArrayList rooms = new ArrayList();

    public Building(){
        rooms.add(new Ballroom()); 
        rooms.add(new Library());
    }
}
```